# "industrialised countries" vs. "industrial countries"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I cannot see any difference between industrialised countries and industrial countries. Can you?

> 1. You can easily make your living there because it is an **industrial** country.
> 2. You can easily make your living there because it is an **industrialised** country.

Answer (score 1):

This is just one of those contexts where [usage has changed over time...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28industrialised%20country%29%2B%28industrialized%20country%29%2Cindustrial%20country&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28industrialised%20country%29%20%2B%20%28industrialized%20country%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindustrial%20country%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(industrialised%20country)%20%2B%20(industrialized%20country)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindustrial%20country%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

I think we can dismiss the possibility that there's any *semantic* difference between the two forms - nothing in the real world has changed so much since WW2 that we now need different words to refer to different types / levels of industrialisation (though there's certainly still some ongoing debate regarding the terms [***developed / developing*** nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developing_country)).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would take those terms as having quite different connotations.  (The fact that FumbleFingers considers there to be no such distinction indicates you should stress the *personally* in that sentence).

"Industrial country" to me suggests a country whose economy (and perhaps landscape) is dominated by industrial activity.

"Industrialised country" on the other hand suggests a country which has gone through the process of industrialisation, but may very well currently have a post-industrial economy.

For example, I would describe my own country (the UK) as industrialised, but not as industrial, because we currently have a pretty small amount of manufacturing (etc) compared to a service/knowledge based economy.